# Convert list of dicts to list of strings in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Here's something I think should be straight-forward in Ansible, but I'm having trouble finding a canonical best practice.

In Ansible, I have a list of dicts in YAML:

```
config:
  - id: x
    value: X
  - id: y
    value: Y
```

I want to generate a list of strings that can be passed as a whole to the mysql_query module.

I've tried various elegant ways of doing this using Ansible filters, but that best I've come up with is to generate a list of newline-separate strings in a single template that iterates over `config` and then `trim | split('\n')` the resulting single string.

Template:

```
{% for item in config %}
{{ item.id }} => {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Playbook task:

```
set_fact:
  converted_items: "{{ lookup('template', './template.j2') | trim | split('\n') }}"
```

But this feels like a kludge.

What am I missing here?

[Note this is a canned example, to keep things simple.]

Comment: You didn't include the expected output, aside from what appears to be `["key => value", "other key => other value"]` is that right? Also, if you are just using `lookup("template"` to run jinja2, there's no need for the lookup template -- `set_fact:` and friends are perfectly capable of running `{% for` loops

Comment: Right, I ended up inlining the template in this case, although it's good to know the template approach works as well.  Thanks @mdaniel!

Comment: Although, preferably I'd have a string variable, and then eval that for each iteration in the loop.  Something like: statement: "INSERT INTO config ('{{ item.id }}', '{{ item.value }}'" and then a loop that evaluates this variable/string without having to inline it (which gets somewhat ugly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to transform list of dicts to list of strings, just use [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops) and [union](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables):

```
- name: vartest
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    config:
    - id: x
      value: X
    - id: y
      value: Y
  tasks:
    - name: transform value
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ result | default([]) | union([item.id ~ ' => ' ~ item.value]) }}"
      loop: "{{ config  }}"

    - name: display result
      debug:
        var: result
```

equivalent of union: `result | default([]) + [item.id ~ ' => ' ~ item.value]`

---

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": [
        "x => X",
        "y => Y"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is the alternative approach I was using (although without the union, since this isn't quite the same, since I need to support order and duplicates).

If I can combine this with an template instantiation, that would be ideal ... and I can.  This works, and accomplishes exactly what I want.

{{ result | default([]) + [lookup('template', './template.j2') | trim] }}

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a file. Put the Jinja template into the local vars, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        converted_items: "{{ _converted_items|trim|split('\n') }}"
      vars:
        _converted_items: |
          {% for item in config %}
          {{ item.id }} => {{ item.value }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  converted_items:
  - x => X
  - y => Y
```

There are many options of how to transform the data, e.g. the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        converted_items: "{{ _keys|zip(_vals)|map('join', ' => ')|list }}"
      vars:
        _keys: "{{ config|map(attribute='id')|list }}"
        _vals: "{{ config|map(attribute='value')|list }}"
```

Comment: Good tip on inline template.  Thanks!